How to make an attribute block within a terraform resource conditional?
I have a terraform module for creating an ECS service and task definition, along with some other related resources. This is used for a few different services with slightly different requirements.
The issue I'm running into is that only one of my services has a task needing a mounted volume. I'm trying to write a condition so that the volume will only be created in the task definition for that particular service - something like
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                   = var.service_task_name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.cpu
  memory                   = var.memory
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.execution.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.task.arn

  count = var.volume_name != null ? 1 : 0
    volume {
      name = var.volume_name

      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id          = var.efs_id
        root_directory          = "/"
        transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
        transit_encryption_port = 2999
        authorization_config {
          access_point_id = var.efs_access_point_id
          iam             = "ENABLED"
        }
      }
    }

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
...

The variable volume_name is only set for that task and is set to null elsewhere, along with efs_id and efs_access_point_id. Essentially what I need is "if var.volume_name = null, skip the volume block". Obviously this code doesn't work but I hope it shows what I'm trying to achieve.
I've tried to use dynamic blocks too but using for_each doesn't work here as they're all separate resources and not a list I can iterate over - unless I'm misunderstanding the use of dynamic blocks.

I think this should work with dynamic block:
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                   = var.service_task_name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.cpu
  memory                   = var.memory
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.execution.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.task.arn

  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volume_name != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      name = var.volume_name
      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id          = var.efs_id
        root_directory          = "/"
        transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
        transit_encryption_port = 2999
        authorization_config {
          access_point_id = var.efs_access_point_id
          iam             = "ENABLED"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
...


I was about to ask you about the count expression, I was a bit confused :-)

Meh, I wasn't sure if the task uses count or not. :) But definitely not needed for the volume. :)

This works! Thank you so much :).
The count was just there as something I was trying, I should have made that more clear in the description. Thanks again!
